# I used OpenFileDialog in Visual Studio "Windows Forms App(.NET Framework)" to open "Select Folder", but the prompt doesn't open. How can I solve this?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

```
private void locbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Folder";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";//--"C:\\";
    openFileDialog1.ValidateNames = false;
    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
    openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Please Select an Another Folder!";
    }
}
```

Here is the code. It should display when I click locbtn, but it seems to refuse.

This code was reviewed for 2 days, can you give me an answer? I tried multiple websites' (+ Youtube) source code, and... nothing happens. I tried FolderBrowserDialog also, but no change to nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but it seems to refuse'? The code you've posted shows 2 dialogs, an OpenFileDialog then a FolderBrowserDialog.

Comment: Your folder  browser dialog needs an initial folder too. You do not do anything when the user selects a folder, you don't even grab the path

Comment: I mean, I'm not using FolderBrowserDialog, I don't know about it. The `if (diag.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }` was a mistake.

Comment: @it'sme, unless you post your actual code and elaborate on the problem we can't really help you. Take a look at the guide for [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange the code so that you can determine what is going on.
Your code has two `openFileDialog.ShowDialog()` statements.
It's possible that the return to `ShowDialog()` is being missed.

Try something like the:

```
private void locbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileTextDefault = "Please Select Another Folder!";
    TestBox1.Text = fileTextDefault;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Folder";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";//--"C:\\";
    openFileDialog1.ValidateNames = false;
    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
    openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        if (filePath != "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = filePath;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      //Do something here to indicate failure
    }
}
```